# Keras - Can my loss be a function of the model parameters?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, keras

I have noticed that in Keras, an optimizer takes a loss function of the form

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    //some loss function
```

What if my loss function is only a function of the models parameters? How do I use said loss function with an optimizer?
Here is an example using a Keras optimizer:

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, 
                  momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
                  loss=custom_objective,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

def custom_objective(model.trainable_weights()):
    //some loss function
```

Comment: "How do I use the gradients to update the model" is a very, very, open-ended question.

Comment: I rephrased the question, I hope that helps.

Comment: This is still very open ended - typically people use stochastic gradient descent, but there are many many different *optimisers.* Since you've tagged the question with Keras, here's a link to the [Keras documentation on optimisers](https://keras.io/optimizers/).

Comment: I have been looking at the optimizers.  The only problem is that they take a loss function with the parameters y_true and y_pred, but my loss function is a function of the output only.   There is no y_true.

Comment: I rephrased the question again.  I am sorry, I am still pretty new to this, so have mercy.

Comment: What do you mean by "my loss function is a function of the output only"? If your loss function depends only on `y_pred` then I see no problem in defining a custom loss function. It can still take two parameters in order to comply with Keras requirements, but use only `y_pred` in loss computations.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2662) an answer to your question by Chollet himself